# Can I create an AWS IAM policy that acts differently when using access key or user/pass credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-iam-policy

I wanted to try a new approach to configuring and enforcing some actions from my AWS IAM users in which they are denied access to certain actions *on console* unless they have performed a specific action (like adding a tag to themselves or activating a MFA device). Yes it would be a composite condition and the second part is dealt with.

For that I would need to allow different actions when the user is authenticated using their access key or using their username/password (namely using the aws web console). But I can't seem to find any way to identify that.

So I guess the exact question is:

> Is there a condition for policies that would allow or deny an action specifically when the user is authenticated by user/pass and not using their access key?

I have tried reading the whole [documentation for aws policy conditionals](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html) but couldn't find any condition that suits those needs. Hoping to find someone creative that had the same problem on the internet I tried browsing, but my google-fu seems to be bad because every query leaves me with thousands of tutorials on how to provide or deny console access to a user, period.

Comment: *"Is there a condition for policies that would allow or deny an action specifically when the user is using the web console?"* - no, there is not, and neither does it make sense to have something like that. The web console is just a frontend to the API, the CLI is just another kind of frontend basically.

Comment: Would it make more sense if I phrased it "using the user/pass authentication against access key authentication"?

Comment: You could investigate writing conditions based upon [UserAgent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-useragent). I'm not sure it's a good idea to do that but I don't know your underlying rationale.

Comment: That's something to think about =)

Comment: You could try requiring your Console users to use MFA but ban your users from calling `sts:GetSessionToken`, then grant different permissions based on whether MFA is present?  Not sure if this will work -- I don't know if Console login with MFA depends on `sts:GetSessionToken`.

Comment: I will definitely look into the `sts:GetSessionToken` suggestion, I have de-prioritized the issue though so it might take a while. If I find a viable solution I'll make sure to post here.